# How to use webviewer flutter with an html file that has list of linked topics?

Tags: android, html, flutter

I'm trying to build an app that view Html files. But I got a problem:
I have a folder that contains many html files and folders that also contain html files and so on. What I want to do is showing the start html file that has a list of linked topics if I click on one of them I'm supposed to be taken to the html file that has the same name. If I do this on the computer with any internet explorer like edge it works. That means all files are in the right path.

If I use this code (_controller.loadRequest())

```
class HtmlViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  const HtmlViewer({super.key, required this.title, required this.filePath});

  final String title;
  final String filePath;

  @override
  State<HtmlViewer> createState() => _HtmlViewerState();
}

class _HtmlViewerState extends State<HtmlViewer> {
  final _controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    // _controller.loadFile(widget.filePath);
    _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('file://${widget.filePath}'));
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: _controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get this Error:
website under: `file:///data/data/com..../filename.html`
net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

and if using this code (_controller.loadFile())

```
class HtmlViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  const HtmlViewer({super.key, required this.title, required this.filePath});

  final String title;
  final String filePath;

  @override
  State<HtmlViewer> createState() => _HtmlViewerState();
}

class _HtmlViewerState extends State<HtmlViewer> {
  final _controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    _controller.loadFile(widget.filePath);
    // _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('file://${widget.filePath}'));
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: _controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it shows the html page that I've opened with all topics but if I click on one of them I get this Error:
website under: `file:///data/data/com..../filename.html`
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I tried all solutions I've found in the Internet but unfortunately without success.
I've also tried with this path `/data/data/com....` and this one `/data/user/0/com....`.

Thankful for any help.

Comment: You wrote an unreadable post. Better show your code in one block. And show the html code in another block.